# Gentoo : cannot modify the hostname file as a sudoer

Tags: sudo, gentoo, sudoers

I am trying to change the hostname of a Gentoo host using a sudoer account. I use the following procedure :

1. `sudo rm -f /etc/conf.d/hostname`
2. `sudo touch /etc/conf.d/hostname`
3. `sudo echo "hostname=foo" >> /etc/conf.d/hostname`
4. `sudo /etc/init.d/net.lo restart`

Only the step 3 fails. It raises a `permission error`. So I would like to know why I get this ? I tried to stop the networking service first, but no change.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because the `>>` is interpreted by the normal user's shell; only the `echo` is run as `root`.

A simple way around this is to run the command in an interactive root shell:

```
$ sudo su -
# echo "hostname=foo" > /etc/conf.d/hostname
# /etc/init.d/net.lo restart
# exit
$
```

Note that you don't need the `touch` command, and if you just use `>` you can also do without the `rm`, as `>` will overwrite the file's contents.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this:

```
echo "hostname=foo" |  sudo tee -a /etc/conf.d/hostname > /dev/null
```

You don't need sudo to run `echo`, but you can't apply sudo to redirection, so instead pipe it into `tee` (an output splitter), in append mode (`-a`, acts like `>>`), and then can the output (because you're not interested in it) by redirecting it to `/dev/null`.